# Apache Ignite : A node (baselined earlier) after rejoining the baselined topology crashes other baselined nodes in the topology - Duplicate Key Error

Tags: ignite

Two nodes are baselined on a ignite cluster. If one of baselined node reboots and rejoins the baselined topology, then other baselined node in the topology crash with the following error.

```
[10:38:35,457][SEVERE]tcp-disco-msg-worker-#3[TcpDiscoverySpi] TcpDiscoverSpi's message worker thread failed abnormally. Stopping the node in order to prevent cluster wide instability.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key
at org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity.checkIndexes(QueryEntity.java:223)
at org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity.makePatch(QueryEntity.java:174)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.QuerySchema.makePatch(QuerySchema.java:114)
```

The Persistence for the nodes is turned on. Using EXT4 file system on ubuntu 16.04 server edition.

Comment: As I see you have already created a Jira ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8728 (6 months ago). I suggest attaching your configuration files and full logs from all nodes there. This will help to investigate the issue more quickly.

Comment: I have attached logs and node config file in jira. Please take a look.  This issue prevents taking the nodes gracefully down, upgrade and reboot the cluster.

Comment: if we are using native persistence, is cacheConfiguration.setWriteThrough() still valid or is it valid only when using 3rd party persistance like cassandra?

Comment: `CacheConfiguration#setWriteThrough` is only valid for 3rd party persistence.